# run mstest.exe through a vb script

Tags: vb.net, mstest, cmd

If i put the below in visual studio command line it works perfectly

MSTest.exe /testmetadata:"C:\Users\drm111\Documents\QualityAssurance\QualityAssurance.vsmdi" /resultsfile:c:\temp\myresults.trx

But I don't know how to call it using a VB script.

Basically i want to call the cmd line and run the vsmdi but i want to do it through VB.net code.

so the flow will be VB.net --> cmd line --> which runs mstest.exe with my arguments

Could you please provide the code for it

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    dim msTest as new ProcessStartInfo()
msTest.FileName = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\MSTEST.EXE"
msTest.Arguments = "testmetadata:"C:\Users\drm111\Documents\QualityAssurance\QualityAssurance.vsmdi" /resultsfile:c:\temp\myresults.trx"
Process.Start(msTest)
```

More info on Process.Start 
http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start

Comment: thanks for the answer but the answer you have written works only for a regular cmd prompt not a visual studio cmd prompt

Comment: Do you mean it only works in a VS command prompt not a regular command prompt ?

Comment: Well i haven't been able to run it through regular command prompt.

Comment: you need to have the path of VS in place in msTest.FileName(I edited the answer) I have guessed that you are running VS 2010 on a 64 bit machine. If this is not true you might change Program Files (x86)\ to Program Files\ for 32 bit or Visual Studio 9.0 to Visual Studio 8.0 for Visual Studio 2008